# CSS SVG Wheen animation not maintaining co ordinates

Tags: html, css, svg, css-transforms

I have a COG i want to rotate 360 degrees using CSS but it's behaving differently i cannot figured out why it not moving to the fixed coordinates.

I want the COG icon to roated at the same fixed position.

You can check the GIF Video i created and also the code snippet to test.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```css
#cog {
  -webkit-animation: cog 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: cog 5s infinite;
  -ms-animation: cog 5s infinite;
  animation: cog 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes cog {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes cog {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes cog {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes cog {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px;height:300px">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 336 236" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-miterlimit:10;">
    <g id="bg">
        <path d="M105.14,76.488L232.128,76.488C236.39,76.488 239.872,79.97 239.872,84.224L239.872,169.828L97.396,169.828L97.396,84.225C97.396,79.971 100.879,76.488 105.14,76.488Z" style="fill:rgb(236,236,236);"/>
        <path d="M105.14,78.879L232.128,78.879C235.073,78.879 237.482,81.292 237.482,84.225L237.482,167.44L99.788,167.44L99.788,84.225C99.788,81.292 102.192,78.879 105.14,78.879Z" style="fill:rgb(26,62,82);"/>
        <rect x="104.676" y="83.408" width="127.911" height="79.256" style="fill:rgb(122,235,212);stroke:black;stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M87.464,165.176L249.794,165.176C251.343,165.176 252.606,166.606 252.606,168.287L252.606,171.851C252.606,173.523 251.301,174.968 249.794,174.968L87.464,174.968C85.957,174.968 84.649,173.556 84.649,171.851L84.649,168.287C84.649,166.584 85.927,165.176 87.464,165.176Z" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M155.345,165.598L181.911,165.598C182.165,165.598 182.372,166.135 182.372,166.768L182.372,168.108C182.372,168.735 182.159,169.28 181.911,169.28L155.345,169.28C155.098,169.28 154.884,168.749 154.884,168.108L154.884,166.768C154.884,166.129 155.093,165.598 155.345,165.598Z" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <circle cx="73.835" cy="49.21" r="21.654" style="fill:rgb(122,235,212);stroke:black;stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <circle cx="264.558" cy="49.21" r="21.654" style="fill:rgb(122,235,212);stroke:black;stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <circle cx="289.317" cy="117.277" r="21.654" style="fill:rgb(122,235,212);stroke:black;stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <circle cx="288.423" cy="180.609" r="21.654" style="fill:rgb(122,235,212);stroke:black;stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <circle cx="48.998" cy="117.277" r="21.654" style="fill:rgb(122,235,212);stroke:black;stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <circle cx="49.893" cy="180.609" r="21.654" style="fill:rgb(122,235,212);stroke:black;stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <circle cx="169.196" cy="35.443" r="21.655" style="fill:rgb(122,235,212);stroke:black;stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M190.851,35.451L206.185,35.451C206.185,35.451 212.566,34.93 212.566,41.831L212.566,77.528" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;stroke-dasharray:2,2;"/>
        <path d="M251.532,104.503L251.532,109.837C251.532,109.837 252.053,116.216 245.151,116.216L238.653,116.216" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;stroke-dasharray:2,2;"/>
        <path d="M286.202,138.863L286.202,144.197C286.202,144.197 286.723,150.576 279.823,150.576L237.872,150.576" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;stroke-dasharray:2,2;"/>
        <path d="M277.437,67.23L277.437,85.229C277.437,85.229 277.958,91.609 271.056,91.609L264.558,91.609L264.558,91.291L258.058,91.291C251.156,91.291 251.679,97.671 251.679,97.671L251.679,103.005" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;stroke-dasharray:2,2;"/>
        <g>
            <g>
                <path d="M274.099,196.404L274.099,197.404" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
                <path d="M274.099,199.232L274.099,201.738C274.099,201.738 274.62,208.119 267.718,208.119L263.134,208.119" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;stroke-dasharray:1.83,1.83;"/>
                <path d="M262.22,208.119L261.22,208.119L262.054,208.109L261.054,208.109" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
                <path d="M258.997,208.109L256.72,208.109C256.72,208.109 250.339,208.63 250.339,201.73L250.339,199.363L250.366,198.449L250.366,191.949C250.366,185.049 243.987,185.57 243.987,185.57L238.653,185.57L237.395,185.552L232.061,185.552C232.061,185.552 225.68,186.073 225.68,179.171L225.68,177.421" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;stroke-dasharray:2.06,2.06;"/>
                <path d="M225.681,176.393L225.681,175.393" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
            </g>
        </g>
        <path d="M85.159,104.503L85.159,109.837C85.159,109.837 84.638,116.216 91.539,116.216L98.038,116.216" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;stroke-dasharray:2,2;"/>
        <path d="M50.488,138.863L50.488,144.197C50.488,144.197 49.967,150.576 56.868,150.576L98.818,150.576" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;stroke-dasharray:2,2;"/>
        <path d="M59.255,67.23L59.255,85.229C59.255,85.229 58.734,91.609 65.635,91.609L72.134,91.609L72.134,91.291L78.633,91.291C85.535,91.291 85.013,97.671 85.013,97.671L85.013,103.005" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;stroke-dasharray:2,2;"/>
        <g>
            <g>
                <path d="M62.592,198.684L62.592,199.684" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
                <path d="M62.592,201.664L62.592,201.738C62.592,201.738 62.071,208.119 68.972,208.119L73.48,208.119" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;stroke-dasharray:1.98,1.98;"/>
                <path d="M74.471,208.119L75.471,208.119L74.637,208.109L75.637,208.109" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
                <path d="M77.694,208.109L79.971,208.109C79.971,208.109 86.351,208.63 86.351,201.73L86.351,199.363L86.324,198.449L86.324,191.949C86.324,185.049 92.704,185.57 92.704,185.57L98.038,185.57L99.295,185.552L104.629,185.552C104.629,185.552 111.009,186.073 111.009,179.171L111.009,177.421" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;stroke-dasharray:2.06,2.06;"/>
                <path d="M111.009,176.393L111.009,175.393" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
            </g>
        </g>
        <path d="M108.291,56.481C108.291,57.793 107.229,58.856 105.915,58.856L67.871,58.856L67.871,26.759C67.871,25.444 68.936,24.381 70.247,24.381L81.246,24.381C81.874,24.381 82.48,24.632 82.926,25.078L86.288,28.44C86.734,28.883 87.337,29.136 87.968,29.136L105.916,29.136C107.229,29.136 108.292,30.199 108.292,31.514L108.292,56.481L108.291,56.481Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
        <path d="M108.75,58.122C108.384,59.022 107.496,59.614 106.504,59.614L66.996,59.614L76.07,37.335C76.432,36.431 77.325,35.839 78.317,35.839L114.249,35.839C115.054,35.839 115.802,36.23 116.251,36.882C116.704,37.536 116.794,38.367 116.497,39.101L108.75,58.122Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
        <path d="M22.904,26.659L44.097,26.659" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(61,52,55);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M37.166,22.104L51.029,22.104" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(61,52,55);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M222.974,21.528L236.36,21.528" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(61,52,55);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M298.526,75.692L311.913,75.692" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(61,52,55);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M231.983,16.973L240.739,16.973" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(61,52,55);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M245.694,137.561L259.081,137.561" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(61,52,55);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M254.702,133.004L263.46,133.004" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(61,52,55);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M125.737,70.863L141.046,70.863" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(61,52,55);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M289.909,68.992L305.218,68.992" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(61,52,55);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M27.897,65.928L43.206,65.928" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(61,52,55);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M145.899,183.865L161.208,183.865" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(61,52,55);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M171.585,183.867L211.058,183.867" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(61,52,55);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M103.318,16.326L133.392,16.326" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(61,52,55);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <circle cx="168.629" cy="121.189" r="26.465" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M185.831,121.188C185.831,111 177.098,102.928 166.643,104.12C158.704,105.045 152.353,111.397 151.56,119.337C150.897,125.425 153.411,130.849 157.647,134.29C159.498,135.876 160.689,138.128 160.689,140.642L160.689,141.038L176.568,141.038L176.568,140.905C176.568,138.524 177.627,136.141 179.48,134.553C183.317,131.379 185.831,126.615 185.831,121.188Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <circle cx="168.629" cy="150.861" r="4.531" style="fill:white;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M160.688,139.715L160.688,146.33C160.688,149.242 163.071,151.623 165.981,151.623L171.276,151.623C173.165,151.623 174.818,150.611 175.755,149.111L175.775,149.109C176.114,148.601 176.332,148.033 176.453,147.416C176.457,147.4 176.46,147.387 176.463,147.371C176.525,147.037 176.568,146.695 176.568,146.33L176.568,139.716L160.688,139.716L160.688,139.715Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <g>
            <path d="M305.903,22.93L305.903,26.249" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
            <path d="M300.968,27.576L304.286,27.576" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
            <path d="M305.903,32.382L305.903,29.063" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
            <path d="M310.841,27.735L307.522,27.735" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <path d="M29.997,42.443L29.997,45.763" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
            <path d="M25.06,47.09L28.379,47.09" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
            <path d="M29.997,51.896L29.997,48.577" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
            <path d="M34.934,47.249L31.614,47.249" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <path d="M126.699,97.176L126.699,100.495" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
            <path d="M121.762,101.822L125.082,101.822" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
            <path d="M126.699,106.628L126.699,103.31" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
            <path d="M131.636,101.981L128.317,101.981" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <path d="M213.823,136.756L213.823,140.076" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
            <path d="M208.886,141.402L212.206,141.402" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
            <path d="M213.823,146.209L213.823,142.891" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
            <path d="M218.761,141.562L215.44,141.562" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(14,60,84);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        </g>
        <g id="cogGroup">
            <path id="cog" d="M290.284,33.954L287.255,34.478C286.552,34.599 285.72,34.177 285.405,33.54L282.923,29.606C282.485,29.049 282.458,28.116 282.866,27.537L284.637,25.029C285.043,24.443 284.903,23.639 284.325,23.227L281.438,21.192C280.854,20.78 280.04,20.922 279.633,21.504L277.863,24.014C277.455,24.593 276.572,24.888 275.898,24.654L271.357,23.646C270.652,23.563 269.974,22.917 269.853,22.218L269.328,19.183C269.207,18.482 268.533,18.013 267.836,18.134L264.357,18.737C263.652,18.858 263.181,19.526 263.302,20.227L263.827,23.261C263.948,23.96 263.524,24.796 262.886,25.113L258.952,27.589C258.399,28.035 257.464,28.056 256.886,27.649L254.372,25.88C253.792,25.468 252.985,25.608 252.575,26.192L250.538,29.079C250.132,29.663 250.27,30.466 250.85,30.881L253.364,32.647C253.942,33.057 254.225,33.945 253.995,34.618L252.987,39.157C252.905,39.863 252.264,40.541 251.559,40.662L248.53,41.186C247.833,41.307 247.362,41.985 247.483,42.687L248.085,46.161C248.206,46.861 248.878,47.341 249.575,47.22L252.604,46.695C253.309,46.573 254.139,46.99 254.454,47.631L256.931,51.567C257.378,52.122 257.406,53.052 256.997,53.629L255.224,56.142C254.818,56.72 254.958,57.533 255.536,57.947L258.427,59.982C259.009,60.389 259.816,60.25 260.224,59.671L261.995,57.156C262.403,56.577 263.29,56.283 263.966,56.517L268.499,57.528C269.206,57.609 269.888,58.249 270.009,58.951L270.534,61.984C270.653,62.681 271.323,63.159 272.028,63.036L275.507,62.434C276.204,62.313 276.681,61.637 276.56,60.94L276.035,57.908C275.914,57.206 276.334,56.374 276.971,56.061L280.909,53.582C281.46,53.136 282.395,53.114 282.973,53.521L285.487,55.294C286.065,55.704 286.88,55.562 287.29,54.982L289.325,52.093C289.731,51.508 289.591,50.696 289.013,50.289L286.495,48.518C285.917,48.112 285.634,47.223 285.858,46.555L286.872,42.015C286.954,41.306 287.597,40.633 288.3,40.512L291.329,39.988C292.026,39.867 292.503,39.19 292.382,38.489L291.78,35.016C291.657,34.312 290.981,33.833 290.284,33.954ZM270.88,46.077C267.845,46.602 264.966,44.565 264.441,41.532C263.916,38.499 265.943,35.616 268.978,35.091C272.017,34.565 274.9,36.597 275.425,39.63C275.95,42.664 273.919,45.552 270.88,46.077Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
        </g>
        <path d="M24.145,125.994L24.145,91.068C24.145,88.324 26.39,86.078 29.135,86.078L49.098,86.078C51.843,86.078 54.088,88.324 54.088,91.068L54.088,125.994C54.088,128.738 51.843,130.984 49.098,130.984L29.135,130.984C26.39,130.984 24.145,128.738 24.145,125.994Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
        <path d="M49.098,89.821L29.135,89.821C28.386,89.821 27.888,90.321 27.888,91.068L27.888,122.252C27.888,122.998 28.387,123.498 29.135,123.498L49.098,123.498C49.847,123.498 50.345,122.998 50.345,122.252L50.345,91.068C50.344,90.321 49.846,89.821 49.098,89.821Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
        <circle cx="39.116" cy="127.242" r="1.871" style="fill:white;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
        <path d="M184.204,58.585C184.204,59.86 183.169,60.896 181.893,60.896L143.658,60.896C142.383,60.896 141.347,59.861 141.347,58.585L141.347,33.876C141.347,32.601 142.382,31.565 143.658,31.565L181.893,31.565C183.168,31.565 184.204,32.6 184.204,33.876L184.204,58.585Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <circle cx="147.319" cy="37.004" r="1.996" style="fill:white;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M171.997,30.938C171.997,31.285 171.648,31.565 171.218,31.565L154.334,31.565C153.903,31.565 153.554,31.285 153.554,30.938L153.554,25.447C153.554,25.1 153.903,24.82 154.334,24.82L171.218,24.82C171.649,24.82 171.997,25.1 171.997,25.447L171.997,30.938Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <path d="M180.924,31.093C180.924,31.246 180.755,31.369 180.546,31.369L172.375,31.369C172.167,31.369 171.997,31.246 171.997,31.093L171.997,28.666C171.997,28.512 172.167,28.39 172.375,28.39L180.546,28.39C180.755,28.39 180.924,28.512 180.924,28.666L180.924,31.093Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <circle cx="162.775" cy="46.23" r="11.275" style="fill:white;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;"/>
        <g>
            <path d="M316.167,101.902L283.499,101.902L283.499,126.404C283.499,128.648 285.339,130.486 287.583,130.486L312.083,130.486C314.329,130.486 316.167,128.648 316.167,126.404L316.167,101.902Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
            <path d="M312.083,89.653L287.583,89.653C285.339,89.653 283.499,91.49 283.499,93.735L283.499,102.924L316.167,102.924L316.167,93.735C316.167,91.49 314.329,89.653 312.083,89.653Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
            <path d="M312.083,99.861L287.583,99.861C286.972,99.861 286.563,99.453 286.563,98.84L286.563,93.735C286.563,93.124 286.971,92.714 287.583,92.714L312.083,92.714C312.696,92.714 313.104,93.123 313.104,93.735L313.104,98.84C313.104,99.453 312.696,99.861 312.083,99.861Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
            <g>
                <path d="M292.089,111.404L287.944,111.404C287.116,111.404 286.563,110.881 286.563,110.098L286.563,107.488C286.563,106.706 287.116,106.18 287.944,106.18L292.089,106.18C292.917,106.18 293.472,106.705 293.472,107.488L293.472,110.098C293.472,110.881 292.917,111.404 292.089,111.404Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
                <path d="M301.759,111.404L297.616,111.404C296.786,111.404 296.233,110.881 296.233,110.098L296.233,107.488C296.233,106.706 296.786,106.18 297.616,106.18L301.759,106.18C302.589,106.18 303.142,106.705 303.142,107.488L303.142,110.098C303.142,110.881 302.589,111.404 301.759,111.404Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
                <path d="M311.431,111.404L307.285,111.404C306.459,111.404 305.904,110.881 305.904,110.098L305.904,107.488C305.904,106.706 306.459,106.18 307.285,106.18L311.431,106.18C312.261,106.18 312.812,106.705 312.812,107.488L312.812,110.098C312.812,110.881 312.261,111.404 311.431,111.404Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
                <path d="M292.089,119.238L287.944,119.238C287.116,119.238 286.563,118.714 286.563,117.931L286.563,115.32C286.563,114.537 287.116,114.015 287.944,114.015L292.089,114.015C292.917,114.015 293.472,114.536 293.472,115.32L293.472,117.931C293.472,118.714 292.917,119.238 292.089,119.238Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
                <path d="M301.759,119.238L297.616,119.238C296.786,119.238 296.233,118.714 296.233,117.931L296.233,115.32C296.233,114.537 296.786,114.015 297.616,114.015L301.759,114.015C302.589,114.015 303.142,114.536 303.142,115.32L303.142,117.931C303.142,118.714 302.589,119.238 301.759,119.238Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
                <path d="M311.431,119.238L307.285,119.238C306.459,119.238 305.904,118.714 305.904,117.931L305.904,115.32C305.904,114.537 306.459,114.015 307.285,114.015L311.431,114.015C312.261,114.015 312.812,114.536 312.812,115.32L312.812,117.931C312.812,118.714 312.261,119.238 311.431,119.238Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
                <path d="M292.089,127.07L287.944,127.07C287.116,127.07 286.563,126.549 286.563,125.763L286.563,123.154C286.563,122.371 287.116,121.847 287.944,121.847L292.089,121.847C292.917,121.847 293.472,122.37 293.472,123.154L293.472,125.763C293.472,126.549 292.917,127.07 292.089,127.07Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
                <path d="M301.759,127.07L297.616,127.07C296.786,127.07 296.233,126.549 296.233,125.763L296.233,123.154C296.233,122.371 296.786,121.847 297.616,121.847L301.759,121.847C302.589,121.847 303.142,122.37 303.142,123.154L303.142,125.763C303.142,126.549 302.589,127.07 301.759,127.07Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
                <path d="M311.431,127.07L307.285,127.07C306.459,127.07 305.904,126.549 305.904,125.763L305.904,123.154C305.904,122.371 306.459,121.847 307.285,121.847L311.431,121.847C312.261,121.847 312.812,122.37 312.812,123.154L312.812,125.763C312.812,126.549 312.261,127.07 311.431,127.07Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g>
            <g>
                <g>
                    <rect x="22.836" y="169.52" width="32.816" height="37.02" style="fill:white;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
                    <path d="M55.872,206.777L22.616,206.777L22.616,169.279L55.872,169.279L55.872,206.777ZM23.056,206.299L55.432,206.299L55.432,169.758L23.056,169.758L23.056,206.299Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
                </g>
                <g>
                    <rect x="22.836" y="169.52" width="32.816" height="7.656" style="fill:white;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
                    <path d="M55.872,177.416L22.616,177.416L22.616,169.279L55.872,169.279L55.872,177.416ZM23.056,176.939L55.432,176.939L55.432,169.757L23.056,169.757L23.056,176.939Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect x="27.778" y="186.982" width="22.932" height="6.375" style="fill:white;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
            </g>
            <path d="M27.778,173.348L42.245,173.348" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
            <path d="M47.512,173.348L50.71,173.348" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
            <path d="M27.778,198.254L50.499,198.254" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <g>
                <rect x="281.503" y="169.52" width="32.816" height="37.02" style="fill:white;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
                <path d="M314.538,206.777L281.282,206.777L281.282,169.279L314.538,169.279L314.538,206.777ZM281.722,206.299L314.099,206.299L314.099,169.758L281.722,169.758L281.722,206.299Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect x="281.503" y="169.52" width="32.816" height="7.656" style="fill:white;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
                <path d="M314.538,177.416L281.282,177.416L281.282,169.279L314.538,169.279L314.538,177.416ZM281.722,176.939L314.099,176.939L314.099,169.757L281.722,169.757L281.722,176.939Z" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
            </g>
        </g>
        <path d="M286.444,173.348L300.911,173.348" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
        <path d="M286.444,196.143L300.911,196.143" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
        <path d="M286.444,200.658L309.358,200.658" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
        <path d="M306.179,173.348L309.376,173.348" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
        <rect x="286.212" y="181.609" width="9.66" height="9.66" style="fill:white;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
        <rect x="300.007" y="181.609" width="9.66" height="9.66" style="fill:white;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
        <path d="M166.219,138.734L166.219,123.186L161.604,117.751L175.591,117.751L170.997,123.158L170.997,138.734" style="fill:white;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:rgb(29,29,27);stroke-width:2px;stroke-linejoin:round;"/>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: transform-box:fill-box and transform-origin:center